# Symfony4 - Swiftmailer : Connexion refused #111 with corrects identifiers and supposed good configuration

Tags: php, ssl, swiftmailer, symfony4

## Symfony4 - Swiftmailer : Connexion refused #111

#### The exact error :

> 22:02:41 ERROR     [app] Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host auth.smtp.1and1.fr [Connection refused #111]

Hello,

I'm deploying a website on my server (1and1 - Shared Web Hosting), but the thing is that I can't send emails. When I use php `echo "this is the body" | mail -s "this is the subject" "to@address"` it works fine but I can't get the proper configuration with Swiftmailer.

I searched a lot of time and most of topics talks about Symfony 1.4, 2 sometimes 3.
I have another website working fine on this same server with Symfony3, and it works.
So I've tried to copy the working config of Symfony3 on the current web site but it did'nt works because it seems that 'mail' transport is not supported anymore in Symfony4.

I have also tried mailer and sendmail which give another errors.

I've followed [1and1 configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqFfR.jpg) on my account
but i've tested others combinations to be sure :

- ssl + port 25 = Connection timed out #110
- ssl + port 465 = Connection timed out #110
- ssl + port 993 = Connection refused #111
- tls + port 25 = Connection timed out #110
- tls + port 465 = Connection timed out #110
- tls + port 993 = Connection refused #111

Port 993 seems to work but, but something is blocking the connexion and i can't 
figuring what.
And the password / id is correct, i even changed the password to be sure.

So i don't know what i'm doing wrong, maybe it should be simple but i don't get it.

Thanks

---

#### Configuration :

**config/package/swiftmailer.yaml** according to [Mailer Configuration Reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html)

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: default

    mailers:
        default:
            url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%' #defined in .env
            spool:
                type: memory
            transport: smtp
            command: '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'
            username: ******.*****@*****.***.***
            password: ************
            host: auth.smtp.1and1.fr
            port: 993
            timeout: 20
            encryption: ssl
            auth_mode: login
```

**.env** according to [Symfony : Using Cloud Services to Send Emails](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html#using-cloud-services-to-send-emails)

```
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
MAILER_URL=smtp://auth.smtp.1and1.fr:993?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=******.*****%40******.****.com&password=******
###< symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

...
```